Accessing Array of records within a Record
I am using a Virtual String Grid to navigate through program source code files. For any file I am using two levels in the Virtual String grid represented by 2 arrays of records. L0CodeData and L1CodeData and for a single source file this works well.
Type
  PItemRecord = ^TItemRecord;
  TItemRecord = record
    RecType: TItemCategory;
    Caption: String;            // Caption visible in explorer
    ImageIndex: Integer;        // Image visible in explorer
    Key: Integer;               // L0 Key to Child records or L1 Line Number
    ChildCount: Integer;        // ChildCount (L0), ChildCount
  end;
var
    L0CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;
    L1CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;

procedure TfmCodeExplorerVT.vtCodeExplrInitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
Var Level: Cardinal;
    i,j: Cardinal;
    L0Data: PItemRecord;
    L1Data: PItemRecord;
begin
  with Sender do begin
    Level := GetNodeLevel(Node);

    if Not Odd(Level) then
      begin
          i :=  Node.Index;
          L0Data := GetNodeData(Node);
          if Assigned(L0Data) then with L0Data^ do begin
            Caption := L0CodeData[i].Caption;
            RecType := L0CodeData[i].RecType;
            ImageIndex := L0CodeData[i].ImageIndex;
            if L0CodeData[i].ChildCount > 0 then begin
              Include(InitialStates, ivsHasChildren);
              Key := L0CodeData[i].Key;
              for j := 0 to L0CodeData[i].ChildCount -1 do
                AddChild(Node);
            end;
          end;
        end
    else
      begin
          L0Data := Node.Parent.GetData;
          L1Data := GetNodeData(Node);
          if Assigned(L0Data) and Assigned(L1Data) then begin
            i := L0Data^.Key + Node.Index;
            with L1Data^ do begin
              Caption := L1CodeData[i].Caption;
              RecType := L1CodeData[i].RecType;
              ImageIndex := L1CodeData[i].ImageIndex;
              Key := L1CodeData[i].Key;
            end;
          end;
        end;
    invalidatetobottom(Node);
  end;
end;

Source code files can be nested so I have tried creating a container record tFileTree which holds the code arrays:
  tFileTree = Record
    Level: Integer;             // Hierarchal level of file - steps 2 levels per file
    FileName: String;
    L0CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;
    L1CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;
    IncFiles: Array of tFileTree;
  end;

Var FileTree: tFileTree;


When I try to access the array of records via the FileTree record I get an access violation.
e.g.
FileTree.L0CodeData[i].Caption;

How do I get around this issue?

How does the part of your code look that sets the length of L0CodeData and fills it in? A guess is that you have either forgotten to do SetLength(L0CodeData, ) or not assigned the element L0CodeData[i].

@MatthiasB As Isaid at the beginning when addressing the arrays directly works. if I wrap the same code in a with statement (With FileTree do etc) I get the access vio;ation.

I didn't understand that, but OK. What if you put a breakpoint on the line where you get the access violation, and look at the values of Length(FileTree.L0CodeData) and FileTree.L0CodeData[i]. Maybe length happens to be zero, or too short (less than i), or maybe FileTree.L0CodeData[i] is nil?

@MatthiasB I have gone back through the code and specifically prefixed all references to the L0CodeData and L1CodeDate with FileTree. and it now works.  Previously I have just put a With FileTree do begin///end around the whole InitNode routine.  Thanks.

OK. Unclear what exactly made it work, then, but good for you that it works.

@JohnBarrat all the more reason NOT to use with for non-trivial cases. It can lead to unpredictable behavior when it's used incorrectly or the compiler misinterprets your intent for it.
